# How to Restrict User to enter only numbers in the editable p:selectonemenu dropdown

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In the below editable drop down how to restrict the user to enter only numbers.

```
<p:selectOneMenu editable="true">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="0" itemValue="0" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="20" itemValue="20"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Define 'enter'? Is that submitting? Is that typing in, is that typing and direct validation?

Comment: Use <p:ajax event="change" listener="{#bean.validate}"/> or <p:ajax event="keydown" listener="{#bean.validate}"/> depending on your requeriment :)

Comment: Typing and validation

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast: Second solution is a bad suggestion. Don't do this on keydown without delays... Both solutions are bad solutions in another way in that it is not really validation. JSF has great validation.Just adding the `p:ajax event="change"` without a listener and add a server side type of `Integer` as a backing of the input would already give you validation... If you add PrimeFaces client-side validation (one line!) it would even work without an ajax call AND you can do it on 'keyup': https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/event.xhtml